# How can I convert text (String) to image (UIImage) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uikit, uiimage

I did update of Xcode, cocoa pod, alamofire, alamofireimage today,

now I have a red marque on my code about text to image.

I am a beginner with coding.

```
func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
    let textColor = UIColor.red
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 24)!

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: textFont,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: textColor,
        ] as! [String : Any]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes )

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

the red marque comme in ligne

```
text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes )
```

with the message: Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'

Comment: just change your textFontAttributes type to `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]`

Comment: `let textFontAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        .font: textFont,
        .foregroundColor: textColor]`

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. `let textFontAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
            NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue): textFont,
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: textColor,
            ]`

Comment: thats not what I said. Whats wrong with the code I commented above?

Comment: Btw you should use String type instead of NSString. And don't force unwrap the result. Change the return type to optional image `UIImage?`

Comment: I try with only add your first answer. now, I change with the second `let textFontAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [ .font: textFont, .foregroundColor: textColor]` And it's still ok.

Comment: check my post. There are some other issues that you should fix in your code

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to change all NSSTring by String on the page. I have probably did same mistake in other page. I don't really understand what defer do and how to use it. but it's working well

Comment: the defer only executes when the method finishes. you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. First don't use NSString, Swift native string type is String. Second you need to specify your textFontAttributes type as `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` and don't force unwrap the result. Change the return type to optional image UIImage? You can also use defer to end graphics image context when your method finishes.

```
func textToImage(drawText text: String, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage? {
    let textColor: UIColor = .red
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 24)!
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    let textFontAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: textFont, .foregroundColor: textColor]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
    let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```